# Remove duplicates, based on time interval within 30 seconds

Tags: time, duplicates, powerquery

I have a table of vehicle ingress to a parking lot. The table has multiple entries, for each preregistered vehicle. The presence of a valid HID Badge near the sensor, will generate “n” record entries within the time interval the vehicle passes through the gate.

[image: Complete list of entries]

I need to remove duplicate entries using Power Query statement, considering a duplicated entry, **the Badge number appearing in more than one row, in a time interval of 30 seconds at a specific Gate**. The **first one is always a not duplicated entry**.

I’ve reduced the duplicates using RoundDown, eliminating Seconds in time, but still having duplicates that are different at a minute level.

[image: Reduced list of entries - Still one Duplicate]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

It calculates seconds between each row and the one beneath it, and also checks badge and gate.

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
// create duplicate of entire table, offset by 1 row for comparison
MinusOne = Table.RemoveFirstN(Table.DemoteHeaders(Source),2),
custom1 = Table.ToColumns(Source) & Table.ToColumns(MinusOne ),
custom2 = Table.FromColumns(custom1,Table.ColumnNames(Source)&Table.ColumnNames(MinusOne) ),
#"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(custom2,{{"Column1", "Date2"}, {"Column2", "Badge2"}, {"Column3", "Gate2"}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns1", "Custom", each if [Badge]=[Badge2] and [Gate]=[Gate2] and Number.Round(Duration.TotalSeconds(Duration.From(Number.Abs(Number.From([Date])-Number.From([Date2])))))<1800 then "Yes" else "No"),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Date2", "Badge2", "Gate2"})
in  #"Removed Columns"
```

Comment: The suggestion was useful, but it does not solve the problem of messy records, such as interleaved reading from another badge of a second car nearby with a greater range.

       Date                 Badge Gate
15/dic 14:31:46 89726 IN
15/dic 14:31:48 89726 IN
15/dic 14:31:48 89726 IN
15/dic 14:31:48 89726 IN
15/dic 14:31:50 86755 IN
15/dic 14:31:50 89726 IN
15/dic 14:31:52 89726 IN
15/dic 14:31:52 89726 IN
15/dic 14:31:54 86755 IN
15/dic 14:31:54 86755 IN
15/dic 14:31:54 86755 IN
15/dic 14:31:54 86755 IN
15/dic 14:31:54 86755 IN
15/dic 14:31:56 86755 IN

Comment: @Dirk So you are writing that your actual data might have two vehicles going through the gate at the same time?  Is there a maximum number of vehicles that can fit into that gate?  Could the two vehicles be traveling in different directions?

Comment: @Ron The gate handles only one vehicle at a time. But, it may be the case that the 2nd vehicle may send the badge signal ahead of his queue position, because it has a stronger signal than the first vehicle.

Comment: We could do a version that groups first, but a simple solution seems to be Sort the data first. Then should work fine. If sort matters, use an index before the first sort, then resort later

Comment: According to your comment, I understand that prior to MinusOne, I must sort (Badge, Date). Could you confirm if this is where I should place it.

Comment: Correct.  Thought its unclear if IN/OUT plays a role at all